# OrientDB and PostgreSQL JDBC drivers are clashing (InvocationTargetException): is there an OrientDB JAR with everything except JDBC?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, orientdb

My application uses both OrientDB and PostgreSQL databases for different purposes.

It seems they were able to coexist before, but today my code stopped working. Upon debugging, it seems that the OrientDB driver is attempting to connect to my PostgreSQL database when I'm expecting the PostgreSQL driver to connect instead.

Here is the sequence of events:

1. OrientDB connection is made (using OrientGraphFactory.setupPool()), transaction is started.
2. Connection attempt is made on PostgreSQL database, error occurs when trying to create the Connection object.

Here is the segment of code that creates the PostgreSQL connection:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:postgresql://" + [...]);

return connection;
```

An InvocationTargetException is thrown at the DriverManager.getConnection() line. Here is the stack trace, clearly indicating that the OrientDB driver was the one trying to connect:

```
Error on opening database 'jdbc:postgresql://[hostname]/[db_name]'
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Error on opening database 'jdbc:postgresql://[hostname]/[db_name]'
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:204)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:168)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcConnection.<init>(OrientJdbcConnection.java:62)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcDriver.connect(OrientJdbcDriver.java:52)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
```

Indeed it seems the JDBC drivers are clashing.

I don't actually need JDBC functionality with OrientDB in this case. However, I can't find the OrientDB JAR that doesn't contain JDBC. The home page lets you download JDBC-all or JDBC-only. Where can I find a JAR with all dependencies bundled into a single JAR, but without JDBC?

Comment: Which version of orient? Af far as I understand you are using the fat jar, am I right?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You should submit your comment as an answer. I tried and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @RobertoFranchini Using OrientDB 2.1.6, and I'm using the JDBC-all JAR from the download page. I assume that's the fat JAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not caused by the drivers themselves but by the `DriverManager` getting "confused" which driver handles which URL.

You can bypass the `DriverManager` by asking the driver directly for a connection:

```
Driver drv = new org.postgresql.Driver();
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("username", "foo_user");
props.put("password", "database_password");
Connection connection = drv.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://dbhost/db_name", props);
```

---

Unrelated, but: `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");` is longer necessary with current Java and driver versions.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem here:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/commit/8e0f4bed41999cf68ae9de229b3ff6a4260813da

It was a misunderstanding on how the DriverManager registers drivers and then calls the getConnection method.

Solutions. 
My suggestion is to not use the orientdb-jdbc-all jar at all.  If you don't need to work with orient embedded in your app AND access to it via JDBC it is really too big.

Instead, use your dependency management framework (maven, gradle?) to import orient jars, maybe only the orientdb-client if you need to interact with a remote db, maybe more if you need to embed orient in your app.

If you need to interact to a remote Orient Server via JDBC, use only che orientdb-jdbc. But you need the fixed one, so you should build it from source, or wait for next 2.1.8 release.

If you want to stay with the jdbc fat jar, again you can build it from source right now, or you can wait next hotfix release (2.1.8).

hope this help,
best regards

Comment: I know it's lame, but not using any management framework (maven, gradle) at the moment. So using a JAR that contains all its dependencies is really the easiest way for me. This being said, awesome on the quick fix. But for now, I have to mark @a_horse_with_no_name 's answer as the correct one since it immediately solves my problem. But I would encourage the OrientDB crew to release a "simple client" JAR alongside the other two JAR bundles provided, for users like me.

Comment: I understand your needs, but the fat jar, even without the JDBC layer, will be very big. And with a lot of things inside, even if we try our best to minimize third party dependencies. Your can incur in classloading problems, dragons will eat your CPU, for sure :) . My suggestion is to use a dep framework and use only what you need.